# JQuery Ajax request not working on iPhone device browser

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax

We are in the process of developing an iPhone web app using extensive jquery AJAX calls to extract data from an XML web service.  When developing and testing on my Mac on Safari, the calls work beautifully.  Problem is, as soon as we test on the iPhone emulator, or on the actual device, we are not getting anything back from the web service.

I have turned on the 'Develop' menu and changed the 'User Agent' to Mobile Safari to see if that makes a difference, but it still works on the PC side of things.

I don't think it is a cross site restriction, as all the ajax calls etc. are made from the same server and port number.

Is there a way we can do javascript debugging on the emulator to see where the call is failing?

Thanks,
Devan

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem.

Check the url: parameter in the object you send to the jQuery.ajax function. Shorten it from "http://the/full/url" to "/just/the/relative/to/root/part"

To me, it seems like a Safari Mobile bug.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - we were actually pulling the XML stream from a different server/domain than the site hosting the javascript.  I am assuming that it is a XSS security measure that the iphone does not allow XMLHttpRequest from a third party server?

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me, many years later running Safari on iPhone 7.

Comment: Some documentation supporting this issue and solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the javascript console in Mobile Safari.  See the instructions [here](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH3-SW4).  It's basically Settings->Safari->Developer->Debug Console.  This works on the emulator, and the actual device.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem writing an AJAX chat for a website. The problem is the cache. Add this line of code and the problem is solved.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: Tnx. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had no ajax POST and PUT requests only from the iOS browser (GET and DELETE worked fine even from the iOS device browser) and fix the issue by disabling async by `async: false` which makes the POST and PUT requests are sent from iPhone Safari. If you have an issue with the GET or DELETE request, then maybe this is not the answer.

The async option is true as default to send the request asynchronously.

While investigating this issue via **Web Inspector** (Settings->Safari->Advanced->Web Inspector) and Mac Safari Develop function (after wiring Mac and iPhone by USB cable, you can debug JavaScript on iOS Safari from your Mac Safari), I saw ajax POST is sent only when I hold the request flow before entering ajax function by a breakpoint and release it couple seconds later to enter ajax function. Simply blocking the request flow resolved the POST and PUT request issue.

I suspect the async option causes skipping the POST and PUT request, so I disabled it. I know this is not so preferable solution for desktop browsers though, found this is the only solution that consistently worked for POST and PUT at this point.

Here my spec ->
iOS: 14.7.1, jQuery: 3.5.1

I used iPhone X and iPad (4th Generation). Both devices have iOS version 14.7.1 which is the latest at this point.

I disabled cache also by `cache: false`, but I didn't get any difference on POST and PUT by disabling the cache only. Maybe disabling cache is a solution to the GET method issue. Since I didn't have any issue with the GET and DELETE methods from the beginning, so I can't tell.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/relative-path/',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "CSRF-Token": token, "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        data: json_payload,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
            :

// GET method I used is
$.get('/relative-path', function(data, status){
    // data is from service.
            :
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think we have solved this, although it still leaves me perplexed.

If we do a 'dummy' XMLHttpRequest straight after the onReady() section in our code, then it seems to 'unblock' any following requests.

```
http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("GET", "/getdata/dummy.xml);
http.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
        // alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(null);
```

If I comment out this code block, then following perfectly valid XML requests fail.  Once again, this is only on the device, as Safari and the emulator will work without this code block in place.

PS: dummy.xml simply returns "nothing"

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was moving the script tag into the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. The issue was that ajax did not work on the iPhone, and as "Steve Park" said, it was solved by handling `async: false`. It seems to me that `location.href` is affecting ajax behavior. This is because there is a `location.href` statement after the ajax call. (of course I'm not sure)