# $.ajax on jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

$.ajax not works properly by using jquery mobile framework...

it just let us downoad html file....

if we want to call 'ActionMethod' then it not works:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'Home/CallMe',
   success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
   }  // edited
});
```

It hangs the system...

I'm using IPhone Emulator for testing....

Can anyone let me know why above not works and why below works while using jquery mobile framework?

$

```
.ajax({
       url:'htmlFile.htm',
       success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
      } // this line is edited later

    });
```

Edited:  **One another thing I want to tell you is that I'm using ASP.NET MVC...**

**Edited:**
A simplest example of action method that you can try is:

```
public JsonResult CallMe()
{
   return Json("I'm your response");
}
```

[HttpPost] can also be applied, if you want...

Comment: try using `$.get`, it's eaasier.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem right now. Could you fix it??

Comment: Hi @oracleruiz --- You can check this link: http://taxicab.somee.com/Mobile/Home/login --- Ajax request is working fine there

Comment: Hi, I used following method which worked fine for me!

$.post = function ( url, callback )
{
    var xhr;

    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        try { xhr = new ActiveXObject( 'Msxml2.XMLHTTP' ); }
        catch ( e )
        {
            try { xhr = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" ); }
            catch ( e ) { return; }
        }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) callback( window.JSON.parse( xhr.responseText ) );
    };
    xhr.open( "POST", url );
    xhr.send( null );
};

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is incorrect your missing a `}`

```
$.ajax({
   url:'controller/action',
   success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
   } // <-- add this
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I've used AJAX like this with no problems with jQM. I don't know if you really need to declare a type in the call but I do in my example.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'request.php?page=foo',
    type: 'GET',
    error : function (){ document.title='error'; }, 
    success: function (data) {
        $('#ajax_content').html(data);
    }
});
```

also you could add the data type for a json response as well

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'request.php?page=foo',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    error : function (){ document.title='error'; }, 
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, I've seen examples where the ajax request was hitting an outside URL which with no internet connection failed.

Comment: could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496550/jquery-ajax-request-not-working-on-iphone-device-browser

Comment: But I'm using IIS Express....VS 2010 Prof....anything offline....calling offline stuff...

Comment: how is calling a MVC app offline?

Comment: I meant my web-app is in production stage...uses IIS Express...and you know production stage is commonly offline.....

Comment: you can't call it offline, because people think it's without a server. Localhost is no different than any other URL for jquery.

Comment: yeah sure....localHost or any other name: i.e. custom-name....all about network offline service....

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe an old post but to make it work from JQM - you need to use Jsonp instead of json due to cross domain issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Known limitations**

The non-standard environment created by jQuery Mobile's page navigation model introduces some conditions for which you should be aware when building pages:

When linking to directories, without a filename url, (such as href="typesofcats/" instead of href="typesofcats/index.html"), you must provide a trailing slash. This is because jQuery Mobile assumes the section after the last "/" character in a url is a filename, and it will remove that section when creating base urls from which future pages will be referenced.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html